# Mac mini as a "router"

Tags: network

I'm looking to use a Mac mini as an endpoint in a site-to-site vpn. Our router doesn't support OpenVPN so i have a static route on the router that looks like

```
10.22.0.0/16 -> 10.1.1.28
```

- 10.22.0.0/16 is the subnet I want the office to connect to
- 10.1.1.28 is the mac-mini.

On the Mac mini traffic comes in 'en0' and via the routing table on the mini should go out 'utun1'

```
 10.22/16           172.16.130.21      UGSc            2     1107   utun1
```

From inside the office the static route on the router is working. If I do a traceroute from a laptop in the office I see it hitting 10.1.1.28 but it ends there. On the Mac mini I've only tried to run

```
sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
```

That hasn't helped... I've done this a lot in Linux and needed iptables rules.

So is there a trick in OS X?

Comment: Please add the system version!

Comment: If it is 04.01.2015 then it would not work.

Comment: Who are the rude people downvoting perfectly reasonable questions???

Answer (score 2):

Does your router support VPN passthrough? You can then setup OpenVPN on the Mac and use port forwarding on the router.